# x-macro conditional error - number comparison

Tags: c, macros, x-macros

I would like to generate compile time error for X-macro for all `X(a, b)` where `a > b`

```
/* X(a, b) */
#define LIST \
    X(10, 20) \
    X(5,  20) \
    X(30, 20) \
    X(1,  20)
```

So, generate error for `X(30, 20)`

Is this possible in C?

**EDIT: example usage**
For me, left number is for example sizeof of some large struct and right number is fixed space to store this struct. If the struct is bigger then available space, I need compiler to generate error.

```
//e.g.
X(sizeof(struct conf), 2*PAGE)
```

Comment: That doesn't even make sense..

Comment: It make sense. I have edited the question with some example.

Comment: Yes. These things are very compiler-specific and language version specific though, which means not my area of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, here's a proof of concept:

```
#pragma push_macro("X")
#undef X
#define X(a,b) typedef int x[(a>b)?-1:1];
LIST
#pragma pop_macro("X")
```

So, we define `X` to define a type of array of ints, with either -1 or 1, depending whether `a` is greater than `b`. If it is, the array of -1 elements will cause an error.

If using C11, the typedef line can be done using `static_assert(a<=b)` from `assert.h`

Comment: Error message is little bit cryptic, but it is exactly what I need.

Comment: @j123b567 You could perhaps rename the type from `x` to `a_is_greater_than_b_at_line_ ##__LINE__` or something.

Answer (score 2):

It is  possible in C11 by using the _Static_assert keyword:

```
#define X( a , b )  _Static_assert( a <= b , "Error!" )
```

Note that expressions a and b must be constant.

Comment: Thank you, this is nice, but I'm not sure, if I can use C11 features in this project.

Comment: @j123b567 Look for a static_assert implementation that behaves nicely with your compiler.